# Why can't Django reverse this url regex that takes one optional parameter?

Tags: regex, django, routes, django-urls

I have an app namespaced under `blog` in my root url conf:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),                   
)
```

This is the regex I have for the blog index under `blog.urls`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    url(r'^(?:(?P<page_num>\d+)/)?$', views.index, name='index'),
)
```

And here's my blog index view:

```
def index(request, page_num):
    if not page_num:
        return redirect('blog:index', args=[1])
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    p = Paginator(post_list, 10)

    try:
        posts = p.page(page_num)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts = p.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts = p.page(p.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', { 'post_list': posts })
```

Basically, what I'd like is to have the url redirect to `/blog/1/` when you navigate to `/blog/`, which is why I've made `page_num` optional. And, of course going to `/blog/n/` where `n` is  in [`p.page_range`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/#django.core.paginator.Paginator.page_range) should navigate to the appropriate pagination page.

However, when I go to `/blog/` or `/blog/1/`, nothing loads, and eventually Django gives me the "No data received" error. I get the feeling that I'm writing my regex incorrectly, but I've tried a number of permutations and haven't had any luck (most give me the "Page not found" error).

I've also tried [this pattern](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#notes-on-capturing-text-in-urls) in the official Django docs, i.e. specifying this in `blog.urls`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?<page_num>\d+)/$', views.index, name='index'), 
)
```

And this in my blog index view:

```
def index(request, page_num=1):
   ....(the rest the same as above)...
```

But that gives me the following error when I navigate to `/blog/`:

```
TypeError at /blog/
index() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

And the "No data received" error when I go to `/blog/1/`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The view function `page_num` attribute doesn't have a default value so it is **not** optional. Change:

```
def index(request, page_num):
```

to

```
def index(request, page_num=None):
```

---

As a side note. You should probably also change the code:

```
if not page_num:
```

to

```
if page_num is None:
```

That is more explicit. Otherwise there are multiple different values that will trigger the redirect, for example `0`.

Comment: Also, it's incorrect to use the same `name` parameter for two different URL patterns. That rather defeats the purpose of the `name` parameter.

Comment: I also just realized that it should be `return redirect('blog:index', 1)` and not `return redirect('blog:index', args=[1]`. Thanks for the answer, and also the extra tip!